# Can not switch to TTY - frozen desktop is shown instead

Tags: 16.04, dell, tty

On one machine (Dell Latitude E7440) running Ubuntu 16.04, when I try to switch to a TTY (e.g. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or `sudo chvt 1`), nothing happens.

I keep seeing the last state of my graphical desktop instead of a TTY terminal login, although it is frozen and not accepting any input. Switching back to TTY7 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> brings the desktop back to life as expected.

Why can I not switch to a TTY terminal on this system? How can I diagnose and fix the issue?

```
$ lspci -k | grep -iEA4 '3d|vga|display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Does this laptop have a graphics card?

Comment: @muru No, only the integrated Intel Haswell graphics. Added the `lspci -k` output to my question.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I've got a similar situation, instead of getting into the `tty` what I see is the log of `startx` command that has been run on the tty which `X` is running,  most of the times I can't even return to my working tty and I have to reboot. Haswell here too.

Comment: @Ravexina Nope, no news from my side. But strangely, currently it works. Maybe it was related to the docking station I used? Don't have access to it currently though, so can't verify that...